# canvas for pixel drawing in GTK3 (gtk-rs)

Tags: user-interface, rust, gtk

I just started to use gtk3, and I overwhelmed. I want to draw a pixel rendering (a function graph, drawn in realtime) in a window. I was able to create a window, following some examples, but I can't find information on pixel drawing. I need keywords to google (is it called 'canvas'? Pixel map? Drawing area?), and some advises on how to do it right. Should I keep a separate buffer and do copy every time I need to update window? Or can I just draw into existing gtk object?

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: [process-viewer](https://github.com/GuillaumeGomez/process-viewer) uses gtk-rs and draws real time graphs, maybe you can use its code as guideline

Comment: Process-viewer looks like a very interesting example. I'll dig into it.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the examples you can generally check the documentation page of the crate itself. There are examples shown in crate documentation.

You can check the documentation of the crate from [here](http://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/index.html).

You can draw your shapes on to the drawing area which is shown as example [here](http://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/struct.DrawingArea.html) on the documentation itself

As far as I have seen, it is pretty much ported with same function and struct names for GTK 3.0.

> I need keywords to Google

You can basically google for the ***GTK*** library itself and the examples to get the insight about GTK and the easily implement with the help of documentation.

[Getting started with GTK 3.0](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html)

Comment: Thank you for link. I was their, unfortunately, all examples I found was centered around GUI itself (buttons, widgets), etc. There was no examples of a canvas-style 2D drawing, I start thinking I just don't know how this 'thing' is called at GTK (So, here is my question).